# validation of emails using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i have data having emails:
data pattern is like: `first_name last_name email`

`data = foo bar foo@bar.com,       foo baz foo@baz.com,foo foo          foo@foo.com,bar@bar.com   ,    bar    baz   bar@baz.com`

It may contain spaces. I have to valiadte all the emails by extracting the data.
**Note**: There may be spaces between words so that spliting by space gives me more some unwanted data ...

```
function validate() {
    email_data = data.split(',') // This will get the all data spliting by ','
    for (i = 0; i<email_data.length; i++) {
        email_new_data = email_data.split(' ')  //spliting data by space

        // Now I could not find the way to extract emails (only ) from data
    }
}
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.. thanks

Comment: http://xkcd.com/208/ may help :-)

Comment: You mean "email **addresses**", not "emails" ... also, do you really mean "validate", or are you just trying to *find* or *isolate* the email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function split the main `data` string into an array; which then can be parsed with `RegExp`. As far as I can tell you only want to get the email address; so, we use a `Regular Expression` to match an email address. If it matches, you have a valid email. If there's no match; then basically there's no valid email on the given segment.

Please note that `Regular Expression` 100% success Email Validation is just impossible; because the RFC is just extremely complicated, check more about here: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

```
function validate() {
    data = "foo bar foo@bar.com, foo baz foo@baz.com,foo foo foo@foo.com,bar@bar.com , bar baz bar@baz.com";
    email_data = data.split(','); // This will get the all data spliting by ','
    for (i = 0; i < email_data.length; i++) {
        // Get emails, change console.log to alert if you don't know how to use console.
        console.log(email_data[i].match(/[\w._+-]+@[\w._+-]+\.[\w]{2,6}/));
    }
}
validate();
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/H7VaT/

Comment: It still works after your edit; I get the email addresses :) http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/H7VaT/3/ here with alerts to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

```
var email_list = new Array();
var k = 0;

for (j=0; i<email_new_data.length; i++) {
    if (email_new_data.search('@') != -1) {
        email_list[k++] = email_new_data;
    }
}
```

Unless you have people with `@` in their name, it should work...
(This is in case you have people with space in their name/empty name string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify a bit more of what you want to do? Judging from your wording, you want to validate email addresses. Here's some untested code:

```
var emailpattern = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$");

function validateEmail(email){
    return emailpattern.match(email);
}

function processEmail(emailData){
    emailData = emailData.split(' ');
    var firstName = emailData[0];
    var lastName = emailData[1];
    var email = emailData[2];

    if (validateEmail(email)){
        // Your stuff if valid
    } else {
        // If email is not valid
    }
}

var data = data.split(','); // Whereever you get your data from
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    processEmail(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate this on the server instead?

The reason I ask is that many server-side libraries have pre-built libraries that do *exactly* this, implemented as a proper parser for the spec, not a RegEx.

Splitting the data and extracting the email is the easy part, validating the email is what will be hard.

See here: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx